# Gmock specify action of EXPECT_CALL in ON_CALL

Tags: googlemock

If we move the default actions in gmock to a seperate c++ file and when testing we Expect_call but to get default action specified in on_call can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible but remember that the default actions/expect calls are set on object, so you need to call the `ON_CALL/EXPECT_CALL`s on the very same object that is used in your tests, i.e.:

// mock.h

```
#pragma once 

#include <gmock/gmock.h>

struct MyMock {
    MOCK_METHOD0(test, bool());
};

void set_default_action(MyMock& mock);
```

// mock.cpp

```
#include "mock.h"

void set_default_action(MyMock& mock) {
    ON_CALL(mock, test()).WillByDefault(testing::Return(true));
}
```

// test.cpp

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "mock.h"

using namespace testing;


TEST(CppMockTest, test_on_call_from_cpp) {
    MyMock m{};

    ASSERT_FALSE(m.test());

    set_default_action(m);

    ASSERT_TRUE(m.test());
}
```